# Emulate touch scrolling by rotating device - tilt to scroll

Tags: touchscreen, sensors, gyroscope

Does anyone know of an app that emulates a swipe touch or slow scrolling action  by simply rotating the device? presumably by using the accelerometer sensor. This could be used for example in a pdf reader app, to precisely control the speed of an automatic scrolling page by slightly tilting the device. Any suggestions for how to acheive this?